# Incrustar un Timestamp Token de TSA en un PDF con PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy intentando incrustar con PHP un TimestampToken RFC 3161 recogido con el servicio de TS@ en un PDF para que aparezca como si fuese una firma digital en el PDF.

He estado buscando y sólo he encontrado librerías en JAVA y .NET. En PHP he encontrado la librería TCPDF pero sólo es capaz de crear una firma digital normal no con un TimeStamp. ¿Sabéis si hay alguna librería PHP que lo haga?

Muchas gracias!!!

Un saludo.

Comment: En este caso lo que se usa es se descaga la libreria al servidor, y pot PHP ejecutas el comando para que lo genereres y lo firmes